# How do I reduce a 2D String Array by a single row?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D string array that has been populated by a ResultSet of a MySQL Database. I need a way to reduce the number of rows by 1 each time a value is matched. This process will only run once/operation.

```
for(int i=0;i<editable.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<editable[i].length;j++)
    {
        if(editable[i][1].equals(selection))
        {
            while(!editable[i-1][j].equals(selection))
            {
                editable= new String[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time I attempt this however, I get an Index out of bounds exception. This table is used to update the contents of the database later in the application, so the name needs to remain the same for continuity. Has anyone got any suggestions on how I may proceed? I cannot use any part of the Collections Class for this, as this is an academic exercise for my workplace.

Comment: What is your question? Is it: "is there a way to do..." then the answer is almost always yes.

Comment: @Kon I think the title pretty much sums my issue up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `username` is one of your table columns.

If you want to "change" the array, i.e. remove an entry, as you're probably aware, Java can't do that without creating a new array. There's a class that wraps this functionality, it's called `ArrayList`, you might want to use a `List<String[]>` instead of `String[][]` if you want to "drop" rows from the result.

In case you're actually not interested in that row at all, you could also add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL statement which prevents that row from being returned in the `ResultSet` in the first place. Make it a `PreparedStatement` with `"SELECT * FROM Java_Test_Profiles WHERE username NOT LIKE ?"` or whatever `WHERE` clause would be appropriate in your case.

In case you frequently access your data in Java by `username`, you might actually want to go for a `Map<String, String[]>`, where the value is the entire row and the key is the username.

You might consider using a `class JavaTestProfile` (I'd actually call it data structure, but in Java that's technically a class as well) instead of a `String[]` to represent the row. And you might want to generate that data structure and maybe even the corresponding SQL automatically with the help of a persistence layer. You could look into stuff like *Spring* and *Hibernate*.

P.S.:

`table` is a bad variable name for the *statement*. `stmt` would be much better. Especially given that you have `table` and `dbTable`, that's even more misleading: `table` is the query and `dbTable` is the data from that query in Java. The names would suggest that it's the other way round.

`rowNumb` also is a bad variable name, as it means *row number*, which usually is ambiguous. Better use `rowCount`. Same for `columnS`, better use `columnCount`. Or `numberOfRows` and `numberOfColumns` but something people can understand unambiguously.

P.P.S.:
The condition `rowNumb() < 100` in the `while` is pointless because `rowNumb` is never updated during the loop. It just prevents the loop from iterating at all in case the query returned 100 or more rows. Maybe that was intended, but then it's confusing why the condition is checked over and over again instead of being put in an `if ()` around the `while ()`.

Comment: If only it were that simple. Where I work, they have a really bad reaction whenever I mention Spring or Hibernate or this wouldn't be an issue.

Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

After much editing and "hacking" my code, I came up with this solution:

```
String[][] tempTable=null;
int newArrayLength=editable.length-1;
Scanner scnInputst = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
String selection = scnInputst.next();
tempTable = new String[newArrayLength][9];

for(int rowCounter=0;rowCounter<newArrayLength;rowCounter++)
{
    if(!editable[rowCounter][1].equals(selection.trim())
    {
        temptable[newRows]=editable[rowCounter];
        newRows++;
    }
}
```